# Redirecionamento de url por empresa

Tags: php, html, htaccess, url

Estou criando sistema multi tenacy, tenho pagina de acesso pras empresas https://www.teste.com.br/pastasistema/home as views, o que eu gostaria e que o usuário digitasse https://www.teste.com.br/empresa1/home ja ir direto no seu sistema mantendo a empresa1 como mascara na url e https://www.teste.com.br/empresa2/home e assim sucessivamente

Comment: Quer reescrever a url redirecionando para qual página do sistema? empresa1/home quer apontar para aonde?

Comment: o endereço real e www.teste.com.br/pasta aqui tem a view login  que verifica o usuario e de qual empresa ele e, ai carregas as informacoes, oque eu quero  que o usuario digite o nome da empresa dele no final da url  www.teste.com.br/empresadofulano  , empresadofulano seria uma mascara da pasta,  mantendo no nome da empresa no login

Comment: Pronto alterei a regra para enviar o nome da empresa, verifique se é isso que precisa.

Comment: vo da olhada e testar

Comment: Comente se precisar de mais parâmetros que altero a resposta, só me diga quais?

Comment: faz 5 meses que terminei a faculdade, e to trabalhando como freelancer nas horas vagas, tem muito conhecimento ainda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71877/discussion-between-rafael-salomao-and-junior-ramoty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você só precisa adicionar essa reescrita em seu htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$  pastasistema/index.php?empresa=$1 [L]
```

Qualquer url inicada com os caracteres de **([a-z0-9]+)** precedido de um nome com letras ou números podendo ter um ou mais caracteres, redireciona para a página de seu sistema passando como parâmetro o nome da empresa.Troque index.php pela página inicial do sistema caso seja diferente.

Alterei para remover home nesse caso ai de cima só funciona o parâmetro nome da empresa você pode adicionar novos parâmetros a seu gosto, por exemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ ...
```

esse acima seria um parametro numérico, repare que adicionei a expressão [0-9] que indica que serve qualquer número de **0 até 9**, o sinal de + a frente da expressão indica um ou mais caracteres numéricos. O mesmo funciona com letras dessa forma **[a-z]**, ou seja aceita qualquer caracter de a até z minusculo.

Comment: empresa foi so um  exemplo cada empresa tem seu nome, como se fosse varias urls, www.teste.com.br/oficinatide, www.teste.com.br/ilmarmotos,
www.teste.com.br/bicicletariadotadeu, algo assim, de acordo com oque digitar o sistema pega o paramentro nome da empresa e pode aceitar outros paramentros na frente, o sistema sempre vai intender que o nome da empresa na realidade e uma pasta mas

Comment: Sim eu tirei, depois que explicou no comentário a idéia é essa, sugeri abaixo sem o home. Adapte as suas necessidades

Comment: expliquei ali errado, a home nao exibe no navegador, fica so www.teste.com.br/empresadofulano esse e o endereço home

Comment: não deu certo,porque esse htaccess at dentro da pasta enginesystem, https://apoenatec.com.br/enginesystem/login  o enginesysem que eu queri que foi diferente